# How to turn off active Zen Mode?

Tags: oneplus-6, oneplus

OnePlus offers Zen Mode app for its devices as a system app. It functions more like an app in kiosk mode and gives you access only to one of its activities, the dialer app for emergency calls, and the camera app. The user cannot access anything else.

Works fine. Except that it also means the user is locked out of their device (which the user explicitly agrees to when using the app every single time) for X duration which the user had set in Zen Mode app.

Once in a while I feel the need to immediately access my phone because the objective I have in mind cannot be achieved without the phone. At that point Zen Mode comes in my way because I can't do anything with my phone except stare, *in despair*, at its countdown to finish.

Here are a couple of things I tried with no success when Zen Mode was active:

- disabled Zen mode app using adb.
- hid (`pm hide`) Zen mode app using adb
- rebooted the device using adb
- force stopped Zen Mode app using adb

If Zen Mode app is disabled or killed or hid when its timer is active, then irrespective of a reboot all I see is the launcher app with status bar hidden. If I try to open any app using my launcher or using adb, it doesn't show anything on the screen at all. It doesn't show any error either. When I re-enable Zen Mode and when the active timer expires then after exiting Zen Mode app I can see all those apps in the Recents View that I had tried to access when Zen Mode was disabled/hid/force-stopped.

I am looking for a way to turn off active Zen Mode in my rooted OnePlus 6 running OxygenOS (v10.3.11) / Android 10. **How do I do that?**

Answer (score 12):

**Note**: this answer assumes that your **OnePlus device** has USB debugging enabled  and authorized already on an immediately accessible PC when you're in active Zen Mode. If not, this answer would be of no help to you.

Here's how to turn off an active Zen Mode. Run this adb command:

```
adb shell settings put secure op_breath_mode_status 0
```

That's it. Active Zen mode would turn off immediately and you can access your device to your heart's content.

Tested on a OnePlus 6 running OxygenOS (v10.3.11) / Android 10 with Zen Mode app v2.3.0 (works on earlier versions too).

Comment: Great answer. I have only one question: How do people find these settings??

Comment: @AleksG thanks. I didn't get your question though. What do you mean by finding these settings? Are you referring to settings as in settings term I used in the command, or the actual setting `op_breath_mode_status`? If it is the latter, I decompiled the APK of Zen Mode app and looked into its source. Came across that `op_breath_mode_status` setting at the center of action taking place in that code. Thought to give it a try and it worked out. That same setting was also visible in the output of `adb logcat` whenever Zen mode became active or inactive.

Comment: You answered my question: you decompiled the apk :)

Comment: @Firelord I think it means "how the heck did somebody discover that?!"